# Gatsby GraphQL data doesn't match markdown file

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

I am performing a query to get some content from a footer.md file in my project. I am then trying to build a button that links to another page using the links array from my file. However, when getting the data back with a GraphQL query, my link url is `../pages/prices` instead of just `/prices`.

My footer.md file:

```
---
templateKey: footer
links:
  - url: /prices
    text: Prices
---
```

What actually comes back:

```
[{"url":"../pages/prices","text":"Prices"}]
```

How can I get just the original data back rather than having the additional `../pages/`?

Comment: Have you seen this plugin? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-catch-links/

Comment: I think the issue is before the content even becomes a link on the page. Using the GraphiQL interface also returns the full `../pages/` rather then just what content exists in the md file

Comment: What happens if you write `url: ./prices` ?

Comment: @ksav it no longer returns `../pages/` but instead the string we entered: `./prices`. However this doesn't work correctly as a value for `<Link to="">` as it just ends up as `prices` with no slashes

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Using the markdown frontmatter you posted and the gatsby starter blog I correctly get the link value `/prices`. You haven't set a path prefix, have you?

Comment: @ehrencrona I haven't set any path prefixes. I have a repo with the bug recreated here: https://github.com/samwilliscreative/gatsby-bug, you can see the footer.md file contains the frontmatter